# How can I modify or decompile Hermes JS bytecode?

Tags: decompilation, javascript, decompile, byte-code

Since React Native 0.60.4 developers can opt-in to use the [Hermes JS Engine](https://reactnative.dev/docs/hermes). This generates an `index.android.bundle` binary that contains Hermes JS bytecode.

The Hermes [documentation](https://github.com/facebook/hermes/blob/master/doc/BuildingAndRunning.md#other-tools) mentions `hbcdump` which is described as a "Hermes bytecode disassembler"

By using `hbcdump -pretty-disassemble -c disassemble -out out.txt index.android.bundle` I do get something that is at least a little more human readable but it does not look like it can be compiled back again and is not easy to work with.

How can I decompile Hermes JS bytecode into JavaScript?
Alternatively: How can I modify the bytecode? Is there a tool that understands this bytecode?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My friend made this tool: [hbctool](https://github.com/bongtrop/hbctool), a Hermes bytecode disassembler/assembler.

This will help you disassemble the file into a more readable format (similar to hbcdump), so you can modify and re-assemble it.

Comment: Is there any way to decompile the bytecode to readable javascript?

Comment: It only supports older versions of HBC unfortunately

Answer (score 2):

Refer below link someone added support for version 84 in his forked repo

[hbc-v84](https://github.com/niosega/hbctool/tree/draft/hbc-v84)