# How to edite a compiled Reactive Native file "main.bundle"

Tags: android, apk

I bought I vacuum robot from Dreame and needed to replace the Lidar sensor myself as in my country (Brazil) don't have technical assistance, but now it is not working properly because it says that don't have a calibration file to Lidar sensor and the menu for calibration is hidden in the APP, I need change one line in "main.bundle" file to be enable the hidden menu, but I tried in Notepad, VSCode, NotePad++ and others, most part of code is readable, but in the begning of the file have some info that is not decode corectly, and if I try to edit and save it not work correctly. Is there some way to reverse engenigering this file?

The file is below:

https://1drv.ms/u/s!AkhlsFXbkbX4oIFHQ3gEFl19OTPTEA?e=I0kIrA

And I need remove following code, to enable the hidden menu.

`&& data.data.indexOf(_miot.Service.account.ID) >= 0`

Comment: How do you know the line you have to remove? Is the source code somewhere available? To my knowledge `main.bundle´ contains Hermes VM bytecode (HBC), so modifying is not that simple. There are some decompilers available but I am not sure if they also support recompiling. See also https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/q/26463/1848

Comment: @Robert, I know the line to remove because the most part of the file is readable, only some parts in the begining of the file that is not readable, but after modify it don't work. I tried this suggested tool without success.